# more efficient ways other than itterrows() on my code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

this code is taking forever to run given i have 1million rows and 43 columns.
the idea of it is try and find pairs which have the same values for a specific number of columns but the 'CA' column must be opposite and we remove this pair as they will be considered reversing rows.

i.e I have a dataframe = df

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'Brown' | 'Bottle' | 1234555 | 100 |
| 'yellow' | 'Cup' | 1234555 | 80 |
| 'Red' | 'Bottle' | 1234555 | -100 |
| 'Red' | 'Bottle' | 1234555 | -100 |
| 'Brown' | 'Bottle' | 1234533 | 100 |

If I decide to consider column B and C, the program will remove the first and third row since they have the same value in column B and C and also the value in column D is the opposite (one positive and one negative). And also they will be considered a reversing rows and thus only the pair will be removed.

Desired output:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'yellow' | 'Cup' | 1234555 | 80 |
| 'Red' | 'Bottle' | 1234555 | -100 |
| 'Brown' | 'Bottle' | 1234533 | 100 |

The code I currently have is this but is super inefficient:

```
df_dupes = data[data.duplicated(subset = criteria_, keep=False)]
df_dupes_list = np.array(df_dupes.to_numpy().tolist())

df_1 = df_dupes_list[:,[0,1,7,9,8,23,35]]

df_2 = df_1.tolist()

for i, row in df_dupes.iterrows():
    if row.ConvertedAUD < 0 and [row.BA, row.OA, row.BN, row.DN, row.DT,row.D, -row.CA] in df_2:
        try:
            c = np.where((data['BA'] ==row.BA) & (data['OA'] ==row.OA) & (data['BN'] ==row.BN)& (data['DT']         ==row.DT)& (data['DN'] ==row.DN)& (data['D'] ==row.D)&  (data['CA'] ==-row.CA))[0][0]


            data.drop(labels=[i,data.index.values[c]], axis=0, inplace=True)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Comment: Start with [sorting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) on columns B & C, so you have smallish subsets to examine individually.   Depending on your data distribution of unique values, it might be helpful to [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) columns B & C, computing both sum(col_d) and sum(abs(col_d)).

Comment: i've edited code as i noticed some mistakes

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Column A', 'Column B'], keep='last')`  maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. The idea is to have an additional structure to quickly find opposite pairs and create a boolean mask for filtering instead of calling `drop()` in a loop.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["Brown", "Bottle", 1234555, 100],
        ["yellow", "Cup", 1234555, 80],
        ["Red", "Bottle", 1234555, -100],
        ["Red", "Bottle", 1234555, -100],
        ["Brown", "Bottle", 1234533, 100],
    ],
    columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"],
)

# "lookup table"
seen = {} # {(key1, key2): (index, value)}
# which rows to keep?
mask = pd.Series(True, index=data.index)

# itertuples is faster than iterrows
for row in data.itertuples():
    # create a lookup key
    key = (row.B, row.C)
    if key not in seen:
        # store Index and Value in the "lookup table"
        # if we haven't seen this key before
        seen[key] = (row.Index, row.D)
    else:
        prev_index, prev_value = seen[key]
        # if the stored value is the opposite of the current one
        if prev_value == -row.D:
            # we don't want to keep both rows
            mask.loc[prev_index] = False
            mask.loc[row.Index] = False
            # and remove the key from the lookup table
            del seen[key]
        # else:
            # undefined case:
            # the key exists, but the value is not
            # the opposite of the previous one

# remove "collapsed" rows from the data
result = data[mask]
```